# How to remove the borders and some white pixels out borders?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have the next code to generate an image:

```
...
fig = plt.figure(figsize=size,dpi=dpi)
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])

# remove top and right spines
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('none')
# turn off ticks
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])

plt.imshow(bt, cmap='g_cm')
plt.set_cmap('g_cm') # Grayscale
plt.savefig(outfilename)
```

After this, I use the next code to put a background (white - 255,255,255) with transparency.

```
...
img = Image.open(filename) 
img = img.convert("RGBA")
pixdata = img.load()
if pixdata[x,y] == (255,255,255,255):
        pixdata[x,y] = (255,255,255,0)
```

I can apply the transparency to background, but the several areas of the image keeps the borders ((gray dark)) and some pixels out borders are white.

How I can remove these borders and the white pixels?

Thanks

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "pixels out borders"

Comment: Perhaps add some images showing what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me OP has some not-quite-white pixels which are creating ugly jagged edges near the opaque parts of the image.  OP probably wants some kind of fuzzy select, like the magic wand tool.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to say is that some almost-white-but-not-quite pixels are not being replaced, you probably want to make things that are mostly white transparent as well, and not only pure white pixels.

Try the following to do that:

```
img = Image.open(filename) 
img = img.convert("RGBA")
pixdata = img.load()
if sum(pixdata[x, y][:3]) > 240 * 3:
        pixdata[x, y] = (255, 255, 255, 0)
```

Comment: @nars Is this image a "before" or "after"?  It is very difficult to understand your problem if you don't give us clear example images of what you are starting with and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @nars Please try to clarify your question. "Pixels out borders" makes no sense. Also, avoid tinypic. Use imgur instead for image hosting.

Comment: The next image has an explanation of i want to remove (Borders and White Pixel Out Borders). 

The green background is only to visualize these parts (Borders .. )

![Explanation](http://i.imgur.com/x2yL7hu.png).

Comment: I'm still unsure if you mean *outer* borders (whatever that may mean), or something else entirely. Do not use the term "out borders" as it is not an actual term. The image doesn't really clarify this. Try changing the `240` to a lower value and see what happens.

Comment: If I put a value less than 255 (for example: 240) will cut information an image (see image 3 - bottom right), because i'm using a grayscale. 

![Image3](http://i.imgur.com/LdjALq1.png).

Answer (score 0):

To remove white pixels with a certain threshold value, you can use the library `ImageChops`.

**Code**

```
'''
Created on Aug 12, 2015

@author: physicalattraction
'''

from PIL import Image, ImageChops, ImageDraw

def create_image():
    # Image initialization
    W, H = 800, 600
    img = Image.new('RGBA', (W, H), (255, 255, 255))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    # Create rugged edge that should become transparent 
    r = 25
    draw.rectangle([r, r, W - r, H - r], fill=(254, 254, 254), outline=None)

    # Create image that should not become transparent
    r = 100
    draw.rectangle([r, r, W - r, H - r], fill=(255, 0, 0), outline=None)

    img.save('img/bg_removal_original.png')

    return img

def remove_white_background_naive(img):
    W, H = img.size
    for x in range(W):
        for y in range(H):
            if img.getpixel((x, y)) == (255, 255, 255, 255):
                # Make transparent.
                # Now making grey to easier show on screen that it works.
                img.putpixel((x, y), (128, 128, 128))  


    img.save('img/bg_removal_naive.png')

def remove_white_background_with_chops(img):
    fuzz = 2.5  # Choose a value greater than 0. Play around for optimal results.
    bg = Image.new(img.mode, img.size, img.getpixel((0, 0)))
    diff = ImageChops.difference(img, bg)
    diff = ImageChops.add(diff, diff, fuzz, -100)

    W, H = img.size
    for x in range(W):
        for y in range(H):
            if diff.getpixel((x, y)) == (0, 0, 0, 0):
                # Make transparent.
                # Now making grey to easier show on screen that it works.
                img.putpixel((x, y), (128, 128, 128))

    img.save('img/bg_removal_with_chops.png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = create_image()
    remove_white_background_naive(img)
    remove_white_background_with_chops(img)
```

**Results**

Original:
[image: Original]

Naive:
[image: Naive]

With ImageChops:
[image: With ImageChops]